# Loading the Different Nib Files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nib

I created two nib files for the iPhone and iPad, so my app will be universal.

I use this method to check if it is an iPad:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

but I don't know how to load the proper nib when it knows which it is.

Does anyone know the correct method to load to nib file, accordingly?

Comment: Load a nib file to do what exactly? Nibs can be used for many things. Do these nibs contain a UIViewController's view or some other object graph? You can load a nib using the `NSBundle` or `UINib` classes or `UIViewController`'s `-initWithNibNamed:options:` method. Which one is appropriate depends on what the nib contains and what you use those objects for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interface files should be named differently so something like this should work.

```
UIViewController *someViewController = nil;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    someViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeView_iPad" bundle:nil];
}
else
{
    someViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeView" bundle:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Apple does all this automatically, just name your NIB files:

```
MyViewController~iphone.xib // iPhone
MyViewController~ipad.xib // iPad
```

and load your view controller with the smallest amount of code:

```
[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; // Apple will take care of everything
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a initializer `-[UIViewController initWithNibNamed:bundle:];`.
In your SomeViewController.m:

```
- (id)init {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        if (nil != (self = [super initWithNibName:@"SomeViewControllerIPad"])) {
            [self setup];
        }
    } else {
        if (nil != (self = [super initWithNibName:@"SomeViewControllerIPhone"])) {
            [self setup];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```