# Make same application for IPhone 3G,4G,IPAD

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, iphone-3gs

I want to make same application but different of images for IPhone 3G,4G and IPAD. Is there any good tool or api is available.
Thanks

Comment: Don't understand... do you wonder how to make your app working on every device, or how to have some largeur images for retina display ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of them support the Base SDK 3.2 (at least) so you can start by building a universal app in XCode.
From there, using different NIB files for the different devices is not hard and does not require any external tool

Intro to Universal Apps:
http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/resources/introductiontouniversalapps.pdf

Working with different NIB files:
[Loading the Different Nib Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280442/loading-the-different-nib-files)

Comment: I want to make just one NIB file for IPhone3,IPhone4,IPad . Is this possible.